# Want to add tabs from /user/* pages to other pages

Tags: 7, routes

When I go to any "user" pages on my site in /users/* I have menu tabs for the various pages in that section, like below.

I want to add the top level of tabs to another set of pages. Specifically, I am trying to setup the Private Msg module, which has everything in /messages/* When someone is reading their messages, I want to have the same top level of tabs they see in /users/*

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried the menu token module?

Comment: those tabs are local_menu_tasks, duplicating the entries for /users/* path to /message/* path should be enough here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Tab Tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module to arrange tabs at your **user/%** location or some where else too. You can change orders or enable/disable as per your requirement.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.
>
> Tab Tamer makes use of Drupal's drag ordering, but degrades gracefully
>   when javascript is disabled.